# How to add a random number for each file in a directory? (Beginner)

Tags: python

I have 10 images in a file and I want to rename them with a random number between 10 and 99 added to its existing file name.

For example:

`FileA.jpg` > `45FileA.jpg`

`FileB.jpg` > `22FileB.jpg`

The following is incorrect. How do I turn the random integers into strings within this function?

```
def random_rename():

    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Directory\Desktop\prank\My_Message")

    for file_name in file_list: 
        os.rename(file_name, str(random.randint(10,99)) + file_name)
```

Comment: The problem is that `os.listdir` doesn't return the _full_ path, just the file names.

Comment: You could try os.walk(directory) that might give you a better list of things to run through

Answer (score 3):

As a commenter mentioned `os.listdir` does not return absolute paths so you need to `join` them with your actual path.

Try:

```
def random_rename():
    path = r"C:\Users\Directory\Desktop\prank\My_Message"
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    for file_name in file_list: 
        old_name = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        new_name = os.path.join(path, str(random.randint(10,99)) + file_name)
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```